# pytorch narrow is not applicable

Tags: python, pytorch, slice

How to do slicing in pytorch? I tried narrow and numpy slicing? Both are not working for outputing train data and test data. Is there any suggestion for solving it?

```
x1 = (max-min)*torch.rand(1, 21, dtype=torch.float) + min
x2 = (max-min)*torch.rand(1, 21, dtype=torch.float) + min
zipped_list = zip(x1, x2)
y = torch.empty(1, 21)
y = [torch.sin(2*x1+2) * torch.cos(0.5*x2)+0.5 for (x1, x2) in zipped_list]


print(y)

train_data = y.narrow(0,1)
test_data = y[11:21]
print(train_data)
```

Output is

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'narrow'
```

However when I do normal slicing, the test data will not be slice properly

```
train_data = y[0:11]
test_data = y[11:21]
```

```
Train Data is: [tensor([-0.0515,  0.4574,  0.5141,  0.4865,  0.9266,  1.0984,  0.5364,  0.7042,
         0.1741, -0.4839,  0.4332,  0.2962,  0.2311,  0.6169,  0.4321,  0.4088,
         0.2443,  0.1982,  0.7978,  0.6651, -0.4453])]
Test Data is: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `y` is a PyTorch tensor:

```py
y = torch.empty(1, 21)
```

Then it is replaced with a `list` of PyTorch tensors (actually, just one):

```py
y = [torch.sin(2*x1+2) * torch.cos(0.5*x2)+0.5 for (x1, x2) in zipped_list]
```

So you need to get the first element of `y` that is a tensor and then slice it:

```py
print(y[0][:5])
```

Comment: Does it mean even it is a tensor, but y is list of tensor, so it can't use narrow in this case?

Comment: @MIT Yes, you are right. `y` is a simple Python list that does not have `narrow` method. `AttributeError` is thrown because of that. You can use `narrow` only with a PyTorch tensor: `y[0].narrow()`